# Quick Startup in Org-Mode?

Tags: org-mode, microsoft-windows

There are two ways I start a new org-mode file:

1) I open Emacs and then by `Ctr-x Ctr-f` I type in the address of the location of where I want my file to be in.

2) I right click the place I want my file to be in and create a new Text Document. I name the document and modify the end by replacing .txt with .org

I find the second way faster but still not as fast as opening Notepad which I do just by typing in **Note** in the search bar (I am using Windows 10). Is there a way to open a new org-mode file as fast as opening Notepad?

Comment: To avoid renaming the file in the second way you can tell emacs to open txt files in org-mode. Also it might be worth looking at the package deft. See for example http://pragmaticemacs.com/emacs/make-quick-notes-with-deft/

Comment: Deft looks good, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set my initial `*scratch*` to be org-mode.

```
(setq initial-major-mode 'org-mode)
```

Of course, `*scratch*` buffers start with that little message.  You can remove that with this:

```
(setq initial-scratch-message "")
```

But what if you want a *new* `*scratch*` buffer?

```
(defun create-scratch-buffer nil
  "create a scratch buffer"
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch*"))
  (org-mode))
```

If you want to change the default mode for all text files to `org-mode`, you could use the `text-mode-hook`.

```
   (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'org-mode)
```

It looks like to set a default mode for a file using `find-file` you'll need to do something a little more involved.  If you include `org-mode` on the `find-file-hook`, then *all* buffers are changed.  That's not what you want.  You want new files without extensions created using `C-x C-f` to be org-mode.  It looks like that requires modifying the `find-file-not-found-functions` variable.  I haven't used that before and my quick attempts aren't producing the desired results. Hopefully that gets you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of useful functions to explore in [norang website](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html), I think that's were I found these `bh/*` set of functions for `org-mode`.

Add an interactive function that creates a temp org file where you choose:

```
(defun bh/make-org-scratch ()
  (interactive)
  (find-file "/tmp/publish/scratch.org")
  (gnus-make-directory "/tmp/publish"))
```

Then add a key binding such as:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9> o") 'bh/make-org-scratch)
```

Now with <kbd>F9</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> you start a scratch org file that can be later saved using <kbd>ctrl - x</kbd><kbd>ctrl -w</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You may want to profile it `M-x profiler-start` before opening the new org file and `M-x profiler-report` after. If you're using anything like org-bullets that requires you to `M-x all-the-icons-install-fonts` then make sure you have set `(setq inhibit-compacting-font-caches t)` (see [github issue](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets/issues/11)).

For me it looks like the following for CPU samples:

```
Function                                                  CPU samples    %
- command-execute                                                  70  94%
 - call-interactively                                              70  94%
  - funcall-interactively                                          70  94%
   - counsel-find-file                                             69  93%
    - ivy-read                                                     69  93%
     - ivy-call                                                    63  85%
      - counsel-find-file-action                                   63  85%
       - find-file                                                 63  85%
        - find-file-noselect                                       63  85%
         - find-file-noselect-1                                    63  85%
          - after-find-file                                        62  83%
           - normal-mode                                           62  83%
            - set-auto-mode                                        62  83%
             - set-auto-mode-0                                     62  83%
              - org-mode                                           62  83%
               + org-load-modules-maybe                            62  83%
          + normal-backup-enable-predicate                          1   1%
       read-from-minibuffer                                         5   6%
   + profiler-report                                                1   1%
+ ...                                                               3   4%
+ timer-event-handler                                               1   1%
```

I'm getting a slight delay when initially loading a org file (even a new one) because it is loading org modules for the first time. Anytime I load an org file after that it's instant. If you run emacs as a daemon, you may consider preloading org-mode so that you don't have to wait on the first opening of a file.